# Защита от DDOS and Flood

Tags: php

Подскажите в виде кода оптимальные варианты защиты от DDOS и Flood атак на Apache средствами PHP

Comment: @Денис Павлик, делать защиту на PHP от DDoS - не лучшая практика. Посмотрите в сторону [Fail2ban](http://habrahabr.ru/post/238303/).

Comment: на РНР максимум, что можно, это отслеживать источники DDOS и запрещать доступ к другим ресурсам, но это не эффективно

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте nginx, будет меньше проблем.

У меня есть софт, который ложит apache, за все время поиска dos утилит я не нашел ни одной работающей для nginx.